# wordpress doesn't remember uploaded images

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, wordpress-theming, media

I'm having problems with the on page image uploader. Uploading images works fine. But when i'm on a page and I want to add an image there, I don't see the images that are already uploaded to the library. As a result, images get uploaded multiple times and now I have multiple copies of the same image in my media library.

Is anyone here familiar with this problem? I would really appreciate the help!

**screenshots of the overall settings of my custom fields:**
[image: screenshots of the overall settings of my custom fields]
[image]

Comment: Have you configure image uploader by yourself ??? In Which page you are not getting images ?

Comment: It appears to affect every page... Yes I have configured it myself and i'm using Advanced Custom Fields to fill the content. But I use ACF in a lot of my projects and this has never appeared to be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

There was an error in a plugin I was using: Polylang plugin
In the settings there was an error saying that not every page and/or post had a language setup. Selected option to set standard language for every page and post and everything was fine!

Answer (score 1):

Check this screen-shot and change setting according to image.

You can find this setting here:-- `wp-admin --> Custom Fields --> Edit Your Field Groups --> Select Field --> Find Library`

[image]

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked all those settings and they're all good. I will put some screenshots up in the question of the rest of my settings. Maybe there's something wrong there.